# Show input area if dropdown value = X with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show an input field if a specific select value is = X.

I have a drop-down asking my users if they want to add additional attendees, If they select 1/2 attendees I want the relevant dropdown to appear.

I've tried writing a function but it doesn't work correctly, as in if you change your attendee value more than once you get some input fields appearing and some disappearing?

I've added a fiddle to show what I mean, any helps appreciated!

**jQuery**

```
/* Attendee Dropdown */
function attendees() {
    // Function 
    if ($('select[name^="add-attend"]').val() == "1") {     
       $('.attend-1').removeClass('nodisplay');
       $('.attend-1').toggle();         
    }
    else if ($('select[name^="add-attend"]').val() == "2") {     
      $('.attend-1').removeClass('nodisplay');
      $('.attend-2').removeClass('nodisplay');
      $('.attend-1').toggle(); 
      $('.attend-2').toggle();           
    }
    else {     
       $('.attend-1').addClass('nodisplay'); 
       $('.attend-2').addClass('nodisplay');           
    }; 
};
$('.add-attend').change(attendees);
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/7LxF8/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle update using `.show()` http://jsfiddle.net/7LxF8/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.add-attend').on('change', function() {
    var elm1 = $('.attend-1'),
        elm2 = $('.attend-2');
    switch (this.value) {
        case '0':
            elm1.add(elm2).hide();
            break;
        case '1':
            elm1.show();
            elm2.hide();
            break;
        case '2':
            elm1.add(elm2).show();
    }
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7LxF8/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can select the li elements and use `filter` method.

```
function attendees() {
    $('li[class^="attend"]')
        .hide()
        .filter('[class=attend-' + this.value + ']')
        .show()
};
$('.add-attend').change(attendees);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LPRYr/